# How are different metrics for spacetime constructed?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

is a metric something derived? for example where does the extremal Reissner Nordstrom metric come from?

Answer (score 2):

A metric in general relativity is a solution to a wave equation called the Einstein field equation (EFE). If you're familiar with Maxwell's equations for electromagnetism, the EFE is very similar. It relates the field to its sources. In a vacuum, its solutions are waves.

The Reissner Nordstrom metric is a general solution to the Einstein field equations that satisfies certain other conditions. It's asymptotically flat, i.e., it looks like empty space at large distances. It's static and stationary. It contains an electric field. It's axially symmetric.

I don't know if that's what you were asking, or if you understood all that and wanted to know how people would find closed-form solutions. There is a variety of techniques for finding closed-form solutions, and none of them is a general technique -- all of them are just tricks that work in certain cases. For example, one way of guessing certain solutions in spherical coordinates is to write down a metric of the form $ds^2=Adt^2-Bdr^2-r^2d\Omega^2$, then apply the EFE to get a differential equation for $A$ and $B$ as functions of $r$. This is probably how Reissner and Nordstrom did it, since they were working in the very earliest years of GR. Circa 1970, I think people developed new, coordinate-independent techniques that didn't depend on writing down a metric in a particular coordinate chart. I believe these methods were more algebraic, but I don't know much about them.

Comment: I am a bit surprised you describe the EFE as a "wave equation". Static/stationary solutions have nothing "wavy" as far as I know. On the other hand there are indeed exact gravitational waves solutions of the EFE (Bondi wave).

Comment: @magma: In this sense it's exactly analogous to the fact that Maxwell's equations are considered a wave equation. There are static solutions and wave solutions.

Comment: Reissner-Nordstrom is not spherically symmetric. The only spherically symmetric solution is the Schwarzschild. I think RN is actually symmetric

Comment: @Andrea and Ben, why do you say RN is not spherically symmetric? It is just a charged mass,[ it is spherically symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric)! Schwarzschild is the only *vacuum*  spherically symmetric solution. RN is not vacuum, since there is an EM field everywhere , so there is no contradiction

Comment: @magma oops, ok now I’m embarrassed. I confused it with the Kerr solution, which is scialla symmetric.